# Not able to pg_dump due to permission, despite having permissions

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to run this command

```
sudo pg_dump -U bm_clients -Z 9 -v baydb |aws s3 cp - s3://thebay.com/bay.dump.gz
```

The output is as follows:

```
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation provider_seq
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE londiste.provider_seq IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

While connecting to database and checking the permission I find it as chief user.

I am also not able to find londiste in the \dt.

I also have run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO bm_clients;
GRANT
```

Comment: @Eyeslandic

got this issue on that.  baynetdb=> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA londiste TO bm_clients
;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation provider_seq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `USAGE` privilege on schema `londiste` and the `SELECT` privilege on `londiste.provider_seq`.